# sdptool search OPUSH For Apple Products

Tags: iphone, search, bluetooth

At one point in my scripts I run a search for all devices in the area that is discover-able. I find all phone names and Bluetooth Addresses fine. I then proceed to parse the BT address to see what the manufacturer is because I want to know if it is an apple product.  If it is an apple product I want to do special commands because the command

```
sdptool search OPUSH
```

won't return anything for an Iphone.  I tried browsing all utilities on the phone and I can't find anything related to the bluetooth obex transfer channel.  The command is more complicated then this, but if anyone knows how to search an Iphone for the channel that will allow me to obexftp push a file to it I would much appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: not a apple user, just try sdptool browse <APPLE_BT_ADDRESS> to check if obex ftp/opp is supported

Comment: Right, I have done that but all the obex channel labels are in a hex code rather than a title like OPUSH.  I have recently found that you can do a sdptool search and just return hex values so I will try each one and see what one is the HEX version of OPUSH on the Iphones.